# Pointer for item in iteration over std::list

Tags: c++, pointers, iterator, stdlist

I'm working on a very basic game and I have a std::list collection of objects that pertain to my game. I declared it as:

```
std::list<Target> targets;
```

When I iterate over it, using

```
for (std::list<Target>::iterator iter = targets.begin(); iter != targets.end(); iter++) {
        Target t = *iter;
                t.move();
}
```

My objects aren't updating on the GUI. However, replacing the iterating loop with a `targets.front().move()`, my one object moves correctly. I think this is because I am not iterating over the collection using pointers. Can anyone explain how that is done? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are copying the objects, do it this way:

```
*iter.move()
```

If you use `Target t = *iter;` you are essentially making a copy of your object and moving it, instead of moving your intended object.

As xtofl said(thx) you can get the reference as well.

```
Target &t = *iter;
t.move();
```

Comment: What exactly does -> do? I am looking up pointers, and I see the explanations for & and *, but not ->. Thanks.

Comment: I believe `*iter.move()` has the operator precedence wrong; if you want to do it that way, it should be `(*iter).move()`. But `->` is easier.

Comment: `(*iter).move();` is the same as `iter->move();`. It's just syntactic sugar added in C++.

Comment: `(*iter).move()` is the same as `iter->move()` because this is the way these operators are required to work for `list::iterator`. `->` operator is only "syntactic sugar" when it is a built=in `->`. Once we get to overloading, this is a completely different operator, not a "syntactic sugar".